# Simple TextWrangler Regex Replace

Tags: regex, grep, textwrangler

I am using textwrangler and am new to regex.  I have a bunch of emails addresses, but I need to remove only those that are @mydomain.edu addresses.

```
Standard Hall,414,Ashley,Smith,"asmith@mydomain.edu, asmith@otherdomain.com"
Standard Hall,414,Stacy,Smith,"ssmith@mydomain.edu, ssmith@otherdomain.com"
```

As you can see, each line has an email address that uses `@mydoamin.com`.  I would like to remove the entire email address every time `@mydomain.com` occurs, and leave the alternate email.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your addresses are in a list one per line, you could use `grep`:

```
grep -v "@mydomain.edu" file.txt
```

**EDIT `awk`:**

```
awk -F, '$5 ~ /@mydomain.edu/ { sub("[^\", ]*@mydomain.edu[, ]*","") }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Standard Hall,414,Ashley,Smith,"asmith@otherdomain.com"
Standard Hall,414,Stacy,Smith,"ssmith@otherdomain.com"
```

Comment: I updated my question.  I need to remove the entire email address if it matches `@mydomain.edu`

Comment: @NicHubbard: I think I edited that just before/after you accepted. This version will be more robust for you. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

In TextWrangler's Find mark the Grep checkbox and insert this line in Find textbox:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@mydomain.edu(, )?)|((, )?[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*@mydomain.edu)
```

Then hit *Replace All*. This will remove all emails with that domain and leave correct number of commas.